# Haskell How to find an infinite loop?

Tags: haskell

I am a complete beginner at haskell and as such, I have a hard time debugging since it's so different from imperative languages. When I try to run this code, I get an infinite list of `Int` and I have no idea of why it's infinite. Now I know the code is probably very ugly and in no way efficient, but my goal is just to make it work, not make it work efficiently.

```
chaineVersSon :: String -> Int -> [Int]
chaineVersSon chaineAInterpreter battementParMinute = integriser (concat 
(musicaliser (freqNotes (interpreter 9 4 1 5 chaineAInterpreter [])) 
battementParMinute))

integriser :: [Double] -> [Int]
integriser [] = []
integriser (note:notes) = (floor (note * 32767)):integriser notes

musicaliser :: [(Double, (Double, Double))] -> Int -> [[Double]]
musicaliser [] _ = []
musicaliser (note:notes) tempo = (creerSon note tempo 0):musicaliser notes tempo

creerSon :: (Double, (Double, Double)) -> Int -> Double -> [Double]
creerSon note tempo temps
    | temps < (calcDuree note tempo temps) = (echantillonner note 
temps):creerSon note tempo (temps + (1/(fromIntegral frequenceEchantillonage)))
    | temps == (calcDuree note tempo temps) = (echantillonner note temps):[]

calcDuree :: (Double, (Double, Double)) -> Int -> Double -> Double
calcDuree note tempo temps = (60 * (fst(snd note)) / (fromIntegral tempo)) / 
(1/(fromIntegral frequenceEchantillonage)) + temps

echantillonner :: (Double, (Double, Double)) -> Double -> Double
echantillonner note temps = ((snd (snd note)) / 10) * sin(2 * pi * (fst     note) * temps)

--Fonction qui traite toutes les modifications d'état
interpreter :: Int -> Int -> Double -> Double -> String -> [((Int, Int), 
(Double, Double))] -> [((Int, Int), (Double, Double))]
interpreter _ _ _ _ [] _ = []
interpreter note octave duree volume (etat:chaine) pile
    | etat == '0' = interpreter note octave duree 0 chaine pile
    | etat == '.' = interpreter note octave (duree*1.5) volume chaine pile
    | etat == '/' = interpreter note octave (duree/2) volume chaine pile
    | etat == '[' = interpreter note octave duree volume chaine (((note, octave), (duree, volume)):pile)
    | etat == ']' = interpreter (fst (fst save)) (snd (fst save)) (fst (snd save)) (snd (snd save)) chaine pile
    | etat >= 'a' && etat <= 'g' = interpreter (changerNote etat) octave duree volume chaine pile
    | etat >= '2' && etat <= '9' = interpreter note (read [etat]) duree volume chaine pile
    | etat == '&' = interpreter (fst (diminuer note octave)) (snd (diminuer note octave)) duree volume chaine pile
    | etat == '&' = interpreter (fst (augmenter note octave)) (snd (augmenter note octave)) duree volume chaine pile
    | etat == '!' = ((note, octave), (duree, volume)):(interpreter note octave duree volume chaine pile)
    | otherwise = interpreter note octave duree volume chaine pile
                      where save = head pile

--Fonction pour changer la note selon l'option fournie
changerNote :: Char -> Int
changerNote etat
    | etat == 'a' = 9
    | etat == 'b' = 11
    | etat == 'c' = 0
    | etat == 'd' = 2
    | etat == 'e' = 4
    | etat == 'f' = 5
    | etat == 'g' = 7

--Fonction qui diminue la note et l'octave si possible/nécéssaire
diminuer :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
diminuer note octave
    | note > 0 = (note - 1, octave)
    | note == 0 && octave == 2 = (note, octave)
    | otherwise = (11, octave - 1)

--Fonction qui augmente la note et l'octave si possible/nécéssaire
augmenter :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
augmenter note octave
    | note < 11 = (note + 1, octave)
    | note == 11 && octave == 9 = (note, octave)
    | otherwise = (0, octave + 1)

--Fonction récursive pour calculer la fréquence de chaque note à jouer
freqNotes :: [((Int, Int), (Double, Double))] -> [(Double, (Double, Double))]
freqNotes [] = []
freqNotes (note:notes) = ((calcFrequence (fromIntegral (fst (fst note)))     (fromIntegral (snd (fst note)))), (fst (snd note), snd (snd note))):freqNotes     notes

--Fonction qui calcule la fréquence selon la note et l'octave
calcFrequence :: Double -> Double -> Double
calcFrequence note octave = 440 * (2**(1/12))**((12 * octave) + note - 57)

main::IO()
main = do argv <- getArgs
          chaine <- readFile ( argv !! 0 )
          print "Begin..."
          print ( chaineVersSon chaine ( ( read ( argv !! 1 ) ) :: Int ) )
          print "Done!"
```

Normally in other languages I would just print things everywhere and see where the results get wrong but I don't know how to do that in Haskell without rewriting almost the entire code. What kind of method should I use to find where my code goes wrong?

I've read about trace, but I can't seem to be able to actually print anything with it.

Comment: Please make this a [MCVE]. A couple of ugly/uneeded lines aren't too bad a problem if you can't easily reduce them, but if your program requires external files and/or command-line arguments, we can hardly verify it. Best give a single function invocation from GHCi as example.

Comment: Here's your debug print statement: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your list is infinite, that means `creerSon` always goes to the first case, which means `temps` is always smaller than `calcDuree note tempo temps`, which is because `calcDuree` has `+ temps` at the end.

I noticed this by refactoring away at your code, making it shorter using library functions such as `map`, until I could read it.

You could have noticed this by running a code coverage tool such as `stack test --coverage` on your program to see what code ever gets reached.